# External program launch and output redirect in FSI and F#

Tags: f#

I have the following code  :

```
let p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
printfn "installing %A" "installing"
p.StartInfo.FileName <- "powershell.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments <- ("/c notepad.exe")
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
p.Start() 
printfn "result ?"
printfn "result %A" (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
printfn "done"
```

The strange thing is that it waits for me to hit Enter in the FSI window before the results are printed.

It's probably a little thing, but how can I remove this behaviour?

I can't find this on MSDN.

Comment: it prints "done" without you touching anything ?

Comment: Yep...and opens notepad. VS2010 .NET 4.0

Comment: how strange. here it prints the message before notepad, launches notepad, I close... and nothing before I hit enter, THEN I have the "done"

Comment: Ah, no, sorry. I thought it wasn't opening notepad until you hit done. I see the same behavior. What are you expecting on stdout from notepad?

Comment: You probably need `p.WaitForExit()` before printing "done". [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput) is an example from MSDN.

Comment: I tried the waitforexit, before and after the ReadToEnd, but I start to wonder if it is not FSI specific.

Comment: interesting... Short note, you are starting PowerShell, not notepad so I guess after you close notepad - powershell is still running and control is not returned to the script. Seems that hitting Enter closes the powershell and you see "done"

Comment: good point. might be some optional arguments to supply to powershell to not hang out there. or a strange nuget behaviour. oh well, I can hit enter until I find, in which case I'll update that question.

Comment: That's not what happens if you run `powershell /c notepad.exe` from the command prompt. Powershell exits immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this behaviour either in F# Interactive in VS (highlighting the code and hitting Alt+Enter), or running it from a shell with "fsi Script.fsx" (Visual Studio 2013 / .NET 4.5.1).

I did have to add "-executionpolicy remotesigned" to the switches to avoid an exception (even though in a normal PS shell, that's already set), but if you don't have a PowerShell profile, this might not occur for you.

What I see is:

```
(Notepad opens)
installing "installing"
result ?
(I close notepad)
result ""
done
```

I'm running the following code with `fsi Script.fsx`. I tried it both from within a PowerShell window and a normal CMD prompt.

```
let p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
printfn "installing %A" "installing"
p.StartInfo.FileName <- "powershell.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments <- ("-executionpolicy remotesigned /c notepad.exe")
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
p.Start() 
printfn "result ?"
printfn "result %A" (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())
printfn "done"
```